# How can I disable all dot on input type number ? vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My html code like this :

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="quantity"/>
</div>
```

My vue component like this :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    quantity: ''
  },
  watch: {
    quantity (val) {
      this.quantity = val.replace('.', '')
    }
  }
})
```

Demo and full code like this : https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/67375/

For example

I input `10.2`, it will automatic to be `102`

If I input `10..2`, it not automatic to be `102`

So if multiple dot, it does not work

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @str, It's not duplicate. I had try it. I try : `this.quantity = val.replace(/\./g, '')` does not work

Comment: The `type="number"` is making the value null when an invalid number like `10..` is entered

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `type="number"`, the browser is doing some internal processing, so the `value` of the input (which is bound to your variable) is a Number, and is not exactly the same as the text in the box.

In particular, if the text in the box is not a valid number, the internal value is empty. When you type one '.', the value doesn't change: `10.` and `10` are the same numeric value. When you type the 2nd '.', the value becomes invalid, so the internal value is empty. Somewhat confusingly, what you typed in the input stays visible, but [there is no way to get at it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field).

Your options are to stop using `type="number"` in which case your code will work as written (but you don't have the up- and down-arrow functionality for changing the value), or to do something tricky.

**Update**: The solution below works relatively nicely by forcing a canonicalized version of the number to be used. The caveat is that your cursor will be moved to the end of the number each time you make a change. You can address that, but [it's somewhat complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549030/set-caret-back-to-its-original-place-after-formating-number/46586009#46586009) so I didn't do it here.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    quantity: ''
  },
  computed: {
    ppQuantity: {
      get() {
        return this.quantity;
      },
      set(val) {
        this.quantity = '';
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.quantity = val.replace('.', '');
        });
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="ppQuantity">
</div>
```

Comment: It works. But if I input 102 and then click between 10 and 2. Then I 
 input dot, it could be input dot. The result : 10.2

Comment: Updated snippet.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Seems your solution is the best solution

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460980/how-can-i-activate-child-category-in-treeview-on-the-vue-component