# Only allow numbers and one dot with 2 decimal places restriction in keypress vuejs

Tags: input, vue.js, textbox, vuejs2

Only allow users to key in value like **currency** in a text box by using Vue.js

Comment: Imho, there ought exist a predefined way of doing it or at least have a regex/pattern way of doing it... Someone let me/us know if or when it is there...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/0s14cbqx/

In template:

`<input placeholder="Name a price" v-model="price" @keypress="onlyForCurrency">`

In js:

```
data(){
   return{
     price:null
   }
},
methods: {
   onlyForCurrency ($event) {
     // console.log($event.keyCode); //keyCodes value
     let keyCode = ($event.keyCode ? $event.keyCode : $event.which);

     // only allow number and one dot
     if ((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) && (keyCode !== 46 || this.price.indexOf('.') != -1)) { // 46 is dot
      $event.preventDefault();
     }

     // restrict to 2 decimal places
     if(this.price!=null && this.price.indexOf(".")>-1 && (this.price.split('.')[1].length > 1)){
     $event.preventDefault();
     }
   }
}
```

In this way, users only can key in numbers and one dot and can't key in anything after 2 decimal places.

Comment: Works great, but word of warning as I was stuck replicating this for ages!!  Setting the input to `type="number"` causes problems!  As explained here I discovered - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650472/how-can-i-disable-all-dot-on-input-type-number-vue-js-2

Comment: Also - there is an issue editing the number once it's typed.  Cannot go back and edit. I'm not sure how to change to make work.... any ideas?  It's the 2nd if statement.

Comment: @Jquestions if the input is type="text" you can add: `$event.target.selectionStart > this.price.indexOf(".")` to the last if statement to only prevent typing numbers if you are after the dot.

Comment: Please be aware that keypress event is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event

Answer (score 8):

For input with type number, this is what we settled with:

```
<input type="number" v-model.number="price" @input="handleInput">
```

```
  data () {
    return {
      price: null,
      previousPrice: null
    }
  },

  methods: {
    handleInput (e) {
      let stringValue = e.target.value.toString()
      let regex = /^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/
      if(!stringValue.match(regex) && this.price!== '') {
        this.price = this.previousPrice
      }
      this.previousPrice = this.price
    }
  }
```

The idea is to check the user's input result. If it doesn't match the required regex pattern, then we reset the data back to its previous state using `previousPrice`.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/edwardcahyadi/qj9mw5gk/2/

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`autoNumeric`](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric) Javascript library works very well.

There is a Vue.js component that wraps it: [`vue-autoNumeric`](https://github.com/autoNumeric/vue-autoNumeric).

Also, it works well with [`Vuetify`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/)'s `v-text-field`, see https://codesandbox.io/s/yw07v978mj.

Comment: Regarding the code sandbox you provided - you should also detach the element in `beforeDestroy` to avoid memory leak.